# Django Templates: How to filter based on the URL?

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a common header used throughout the site. On some pages, based on the URI we're at, I'd like to include/exclude some html content. What would be the proper way to do it? I see a 'url' tag but that obviously isn't it (doesn't seem to work for me at all in fact, on Django 1.5.5). I was hoping for a simple filter, something like:

```
{% if url == '/dashboard/' %}
   <!-- conditional html content -->
{% endif %}
```

I know that I could pass some custom data from the View action via its context, then check against it in the template, but that feels a bit.. excessive/iffy (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request.path` in the template to get the current url like so:

```
{% if request.path == '/dashboard/' %}
   <!-- conditional html content -->
{% endif %}
```

For this to work you must have `django.core.context_processors.request` listed in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your `settings.py` file.